# Changing a setting in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I was looking at the download bar in Google Chrome, and I was wondering how easy it would be to change a setting within Google Chrome itself.

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

When the download is occurring, there is a countdown (e.g. `2 hours remaining`).

I was wondering how difficult it would be, just for lols, to change that `hours` string into something else.

I'm sure this is an unusual question, but I'd like to know.

Comment: Very easy, just change the Chromium source code and compile. Definitely look into programming and compilation to get an understanding how you can customize open-source programs...

Comment: Those are *not* settings, but part of the translation data (or in many cases the program data itself).

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do one of two things:

1. Obtain the source (Chrome is based on Chromium, which is open source), modify that string, and recompile. This might be quite easy, for internationalization purposes strings like that are probably contained in easy to edit language definition files.
2. Change the string in-execution or in-memory, perhaps by intercepting WPF draw instructions. I seem to recall that there used to be a tool that did this for lulz (point it at a WPF label and it does some quick memory-editing), but I suspect new security mechanisms might make this more difficult.